# Why is the TVR Cerbera Speed 12 the most used car in drifting?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I'm going to start to make the drift events, and I noticed that all the weeks the most used car is TVR Cerbera Speed 12.

Is for something special? Because is easy to use? 
Is really the best car for drift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following make the TVR a good choice for drifting:

- FR Layout
- Low Weight
- High Power

It also looks cool :-)